# Free convective heat transfer for water

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

The value of the free convective heat transfer for water vary between: $50$  to 
 $3000 (W/(m^2K))$. What is it that makes it vary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free (often called natural) convection is fairly complex and relies on a large number of factors.

You can see on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_convection#Parameters) for parameters we are given several equations.

You have the [Rayleigh Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_number) $$Ra = \frac { \rho _0 g \beta \Delta TL^3}{\alpha \mu}$$

Which is based off of several factors governed by the temperature difference and fluid properties at specific temperatures.

You can also find a [Prandtl Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prandtl_number) $$Pr = \frac {\nu}{\alpha}$$

which is again dependent on the fluid properties at a specific temperature.

Then you can put it all into this relation for [Nusselt number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusselt_number)
$$Nu = \left[Nu_0^{\frac 12}  +Ra^{\frac 16}\left( \frac{f_4(Pr)}{300}\right)^{\frac 16}\right]^2$$

where $$f_4(Pr) = \left[ 1+ \left(\frac{0.5}{Pr}\right)^{\frac 9{16}}\right]^{\frac {-16}9}$$

and $Nu_o$ depends on the geometry (some common values are shown on the wikipedia page).

Great news, we aren't even done yet.

From the Nusselt number we can finally find the heat transfer coefficient from the relation $$Nu_L = \frac {hL}k$$ where L is a characteristic length (which relates to the geometry again), $k$ is the conductive heat transfer coefficient, and $h$ is the convective heat transfer coefficient (what we want).

You also have to be careful to use the correct equation for Nusselt number, as the one I've shown here is one version of the "Average" Nusselt number under specific geometric orientation.  There is also a local Nusselt number with a similar formula (on the wikipedia page for Nusselt number that I had linked).

Really I am trying to illustrate (by regurgitating wikipedia equations since I can't find heat transfer text in my house) is that it depends on a lot of factors in fairly complicated ways, and I've only scratched the surface of solving convection with what is actually shown here.

Comment: And how do these numbers interact with each other? I've seen [link](http://www.brighthubengineering.com/hvac/91056-calculation-of-forced-convection-heat-transfer-coefficients/) here that to calculate the heat transfer coefficient you have to multiply them. $Ra=Pr*Gr$ then, with these two $Nu$ equations, [link](https://i.gyazo.com/329135130bded2623a81fcb2a1fedc43.png) you can calculate the coefficient $h$. As you said, the first $Nu$ equation is for a horizontal cylinder (I dont understand why horizontal, and why only it's diameter is necessary for the calculations?). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The diameter is a fairly common occurrence in problems that involve boundary layers in fluids.  It's a characteristic dimension thay has to do with how flow properties are formulated.  There's a lot of background knowledge that helps to understand this, but an answer covering that would really be a textbook.  As far as $Ra = Pr * Gr$ you can see in your second link that only applies for some values of Ra.

Answer (score 2):

The free convective heat transfer coefficient depends strongly on the orientation of the surface and also on the surface geometry.  Certainly, the free convection heat transfer coefficient from a flat horizontal surface will be very different from that from a flat vertical surface.  In the case of the vertical surface, the coefficient will also depend on the vertical length of the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Natural convection arises from the density variation due to temperature difference. It is gravity driven. Obviously if temperature gradient is larger, density gradient is also larger, leading to a larger heat transfer coefficient. Various geometry and orientations also affect heat transfer depending on how buoyancy induced flow is affected. Generally speaking, horizontal surfaces melt more quickly because flow is driven the vertical direction and heat transfer is accelerated by flow.